# Why MaterialApp is not loading after successful auth?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter, trying with sound null safety, but I cannot figure out why the Home() widget is never presented. The user cannot go past the login screen.

I use a StreamProvider to inform the Wrapper() widget about changes in the authenticated user.
When user.id differs from an empty string then the Wrapper() should return a MaterialApp() that apparently never shows.

I tried to debug with print(), it shows that user.id has a value but nothing more.

I probably used an overall wrong approach in the first place, since I am adapting some not null safe code taken from a tutorial... but at this point (from a learning perspective) I am also very curious to see how to debug this.

This is the debug console output when the app starts

```
>>>>>>> main: start
MyApp: start
MyApp: still waiting...
Wrapper: start
MyApp: Error with  StreamProvider<UserModel>
MyApp: Error is : Unexpected null value.
Wrapper: start
```

And this is what happens after a successful login attempt:

```
AuthService: signing in with email and password
AuthService: waiting for signInWithEmailAndPassword
Debug: AuthService wait finished. Userid ANDxpHh85let0fEM1WYGut3vFZG2
Wrapper: start
Wrapper: user.id: ANDxpHh85let0fEM1WYGut3vFZG2
```

main.dart:

```
void main() {
  print(">>>>>>> main: start");
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(Cocco());
}

class Cocco extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _firebaseInit = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('MyApp: start');
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _firebaseInit,
      builder: (context, initResult) {
        if (initResult.hasError) {
          print("MyApp: error initialising Firebase");
          return ErrorScreen(text: initResult.error.toString());
        }
        if (initResult.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
            value: AuthService().user,
            initialData: UserModel(''),
            catchError: (context, err) {
              print('MyApp: Error with  StreamProvider<UserModel>');
              print('MyApp: Error is : ' + err.toString());
              return UserModel('');
            },
            child: Container(
              child: MaterialApp(
                home: Wrapper(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }

        // Show spinner if future is still uncertain
        print("MyApp: still waiting...");
        return Loading();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my wrapper.dart

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Wrapper: start');

    final user = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);

    // If user has no id, then load auth routes
    if (user.id == '') {
      return MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/signin',
        routes: {
          '/signin': (context) => SignIn(),
          '/signup': (context) => SignUp(),
        },
      );
    }

    print('Wrapper: user.id: ' + user.id);
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Home(),
        '/addAssessment': (context) => T4CAssessment(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

signin.dart

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  AuthService _authService = AuthService();
  String _email = '';
  String _password = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Accedi"),
        ),
        body: Form(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'email',
                  ),
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                  onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                    _email = val;
                  }),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'password',
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                  onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                    _password = val;
                  }),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      _authService.signIn(_email, _password);
                    },
                    child: Text('Accedi'),
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Non hai ancora account? '),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/signup');
                      },
                      child: Text('Registrati!'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

services/auth.dart

```
class AuthService {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  UserModel _userFromFirabase(User user) {
    return UserModel(user.uid);
  }

  Stream<UserModel> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map((user) => _userFromFirabase(user!));
  }

  Future<UserModel?> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    print('AuthService: signing in with email and passwrod');
    try {
      print('AuthService: waiting for signInWithEmailAndPassword');

      UserCredential userCred = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      print('Debug: AuthService wait finished. Userid ' + userCred.user!.uid);
      return _userFromFirabase(userCred.user!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      print('Debug: AuthService wait finished.');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: because your code has not redirected the request to the home path ("/"). In addition, I'm pretty sure that you are missing an await here `_authService.signIn(_email, _password);`

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo you mean that I should redirect, maybe with Navigator, after _authService.signIn() ?

Comment: on the success of the signIng. Flutter doesn't know when displaying the Home View but knows only what is the view to return when you require some path like "/".

Comment: I must say, this works:
                      await _authService.signIn(_email, _password);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');

Comment: So, you can upvode my answer below :)

Comment: ..but only when login is correct.
I don't understand, I thought that using StreamProvider would remove the need to push the route, in this case

Comment: my answer below cover also the error login. The StreamProvider is only a map <Path, View> you don't put any information on when displaying this view. This is like all the framework in the last 10 years. Use the mediator pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using in the wrong way async function, in your onPress event.

Another problem is that you are missing the error in case of the sig-in fails and to redirect the call in case of success of the success of sign-in.

The following code can be a solution that solves your problem.

```
  onPressed: () {
    _authService.signIn().then((userModel) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/");
    }).catchError(() => print("not able to be reached"));
```

In your code there are two problems, you never redirect the request view in the home path `"/"`. An you never await the async function `_authService.signIn()`